# Java Select already drawn shape/s with drawing rectangle around it

Tags: java

How to select already drawn single or multiple shapes . I want to select shapes when i draw rectangle around it and when i click on blank area it de-seletects it. I need selection for copy, paste, move and delete operation.

Note: I am maintaining a list for shapes. Below is code what i have done so far.

I don't know where to start to achieve this functionality.

Any help will be appreciated ! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add mouse listener to the drawing panel.
2. In mouse pressed event, store the point.
3. In mouse released event, compute a rectangle that contains both mouse pressed point and mouse released point.
4. Loop through all shapes, if any shape surrounded by this rectangle mark it selected, else mark deselected.